# how to use enum data type in a table in react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, antd, redux-thunk

First of all, I am really sorry for not being able to write the write questions; I am new to coding and I am not sure what the right terminology to use.

Here is the detail of the problem that I am trying to solve:

1. The variable Data Type is a column in the table.
2. We have a button that when it is clicked; it will show all the variable data type in this column and the user can collect the desired data type and the table will be populated with those data only that is related to this specific data type.
3. We have an enum data type for this entry.
4. We are using React in our application.
   How do I achieve doing the above? appreciate your help.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzsBB.png)

Comment: You must write explicit code to demonstrate your problem, and you must show what code you wrote to try and solve it.